# Looking for solution to avoid eval()

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create some sort of knowledge data base for updates (using PHP and MySQL).
Im using a database to store every update in HTML format.
People that are using the system work with different languages (information about users is stored in the DB).
Sometime the updates contain a text that should be translated and displayed taking into consideration the language that the user is working with.

What approach would you suggest, having in mind that i would like to avoid storing PHP and HTML in the DB.

I was thinking to create a col for every language and to store there the translation of every update, but what will happen it the update contains 2 different translations.

Prototype of the updates:

Some initial text

---

Translation of some part of the text

---

Some more text

---

Second translation

---

Final update text

Comment: More than avoid eval on php+html from the database. Do not do it. Scrap the project if you can find no other option. (there are other options)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand the question at all. What are you going to use eval() for?

Comment: I was thinking to store in the DB PHP code that will display the entire update and selecting the translation that needs to be displayed using the login information (language) of the user. e.g. if($_SESSION['language']=='FR') echo "Bla bla";

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table for languages and a table for updates. Then create a table that links languages to updates. One column for id, one column for language id, one column for update id. Then, you will be able to handle an update with multiple translations.

Comment: Nice one, but sometime i will have to display the translation in the middle of the update. e.g. UpdateText, Translation, MoreUpdateText, Translation2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use some sort of cdata tag, or something that you could parse easily enough. But this would be a very "wiki" based solution so there are patterns to follow to avoid mixing.

Example:

```
[English<-[This is the best update ever]->]
[Swedish<-[Detta är den bästa uppdateringen någonsin]->]
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution that i could think of, but isnt it too lame?

Comment: It all depends on you. SO uses stars for italic and bold texts, you be the judge ;)